# can rectangleShape be find using Me.Controls.Find("", True)(0) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

`p1` is the name of the rectangle shape

```
c = Me.Controls.Find("a1", True)(0)
ctype(c, RectangleShape).FillColor = Color.Gray
```

Error appearing is *Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

Comment: If the name is `p1` then why as you looking for `a1`? Also I would do `TryCast` and check for `Nothing` before trying to change it's properties.

Answer (score 1):

RectangleShape is not a Control so Controls.Find() can never find it.  You'll get back an empty array, kaboom when you index it.  You have to iterate the ShapeContainer.Shapes collection with For Each.  So, roughly:

```
    For Each shp As Shape In ShapeContainer1.Shapes
        If TypeOf shp Is RectangleShape AndAlso shp.Name = "a1" Then
            DirectCast(shp, RectangleShape).FillColor = Color.Gray
        End If
    Next
```

Where "ShapeContainer1" is the otherwise well hidden control that acts as the host of the shape.